# Visual Studio Code file too large for outline

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am developing a Document Symbol Provider for a proprietary language, and it seems to be working pretty well for the most part, but I just added a level of detail to my implementation, and am now getting a message in the outline panel:

> We are sorry, but this file is too large for showing an outline

The file is indeed our largest file, and at least some other files seem to work alright. Furthermore, the breadcrumb bar suggests my implementation is correct because that still works and shows what I want. What limit am I hitting? I want to make sure that I don't have some implementation error that's blowing up the data I'm providing unnecessarily before I add some option to limit the level of detail in the outline view. Or if I can know what the limit is, maybe I can automatically apply this switch so that if it's too much, I won't provide the extra detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just searched the VSCode sources for references to this string, but curiously enough couldn't find anything. However, going back to the tag for 1.31.0 I had more success:

```ts
let newSize = TreeElement.size(model);
if (newSize > 7500) {
    // this is a workaround for performance issues with the tree: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/18180
    return this._showMessage(localize('too-many-symbols', "We are sorry, but this file is too large for showing an outline."));
}
```

So it looks like the limitation was **7500 items**, but the limit [has already been lifted since](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/commit/17d85e8361e04937fd7cf227299c7a3a90f2d422#diff-9ae19357b61c680a23031af1efae3a35). I suggest you try out a 1.32 Insider's build.